# Почему я не могу получить только что созданый обьект mongodb?

Tags: typescript, angular2, meteor

Собственно, только начал развиваться в мире Angular Meteor, и тут у меня такая подстава (код на стороне клиента):

```
addBook()
  {
    BookCollection.insert(
      this.book , ( err , insertedBook_id )=>
      {
        this.book_saved = true;
        console.log( insertedBook_id ); //MdfQRZZiBvw7EjFZA
        console.log(
          BookCollection.find( { _id : insertedBook_id } )
            .fetch() // == [] ??????
        );
        //this.router.navigate(['/book', insertedBook_id]);
      }
    );
  }
```

Чтото я сомневаюсь, что это изза того, что я не обрабатываю ошибку, но ведь она и не возникает... В общем, буду крайне признателен за совет =)

P. S. Есть подозрение, что это изза того, что это первый элемент в коллекции (коллекция вообще пустая, но после нескольких секунд в базе данных точно есть запись).

PSS Попробовал `BookCollection.find().fetch() //== [], тоесть, вообще нифига не добавилось.

```
console.log(err) //== undefined
```

Comment: а за чем вы вытаскиваете объект после insert?

Comment: А у вас точно никакой ошибки в err нет?

Comment: Я хочу сгенерировать ссылку на созданную книгу.  Там строка закомментирована, но когда перехожу на ту страницу, книги еще нет...